# Simple log file viewer

Tags: logging, analyzer, viewer

A couple years ago, a coworker introduced me to a simple log viewer that would pretty much just highlight lines of interest in a log file, such as where something failed.

Recently I have been trying to find something similar, but there's such a wide variety of programs out there for different purposes, I'm wondering if someone would have any recommendations?

I will primarily only be using it to look over log files generated by scripted application installs, logs from our OS imaging system, and probably the occasional log from Powershell.  It doesn't need to be complicated, I just want to simplify the task of digging through a file to find the errors.  For example, if all it does is highlight the rows that contain an error, that would work just fine.  I'm open to something third party, as well as something built into Windows, just want to simplify my life a little.

Comment: Are logs text files? Use grep with color.

Comment: I'm normally find with CLI options, but in this case I'm looking for a simple GUI program.

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://sourceforge.net/projects/iislogviewer/ for IIS logs and it is nice tool.

For other OS logs you can try CMTrace.exe located in 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\tools\

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/system-center-configuration-manager

Comment: I think I need something a little more generic.  We don't use SCCM here, so I don't have the full path you mentioned above.